# Which is my public ssh key for the remote server

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh

I often access a remote server via ssh and I generated the keys long ago, so accessed the remote via:

```
ssh -p 2222 root@193.xx.xx.xx -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432
```

Due to a security upgrade, the guys at the remote said the port mapping has been deleted and asked for my `ssh pub key` so they give me access.

But then I added other `ssh` keys, so I cannot tell which key is for this remote server.

```
~$ ls ~/.ssh/*.pub
/home/akil/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub  /home/akil/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub  /home/akil/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

How I do know which key is associated to this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them `/home/akil/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Based upon the file name, that's the first public key you generated.

It won't matter which one you give them, as long as you have the corresponding private key.

Comment: Ah, I see.. Many thanks.